# Move Azure resources from a directory to another directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In my Azure account, I have multiple directories () associated to my personal Microsoft account.

[image: see image]

The directory in the middle, that was completely blackened, belongs to someone else and the subscription was shared to me as Owner. Is it possible to move any resource that I will deploy in that directory to be transferred in any of the two other "gmail" directories there?

For example, I need to move it because the subscription from that directory in the middle expires or was canceled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are few restrictions in place which has to be taken into consideration prior to migrating any resource in Azure. It is outlined here in detail: [Checklist Before Moving Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#checklist-before-moving-resources)

Here is a snippet from the above documentation which should help you.

> The **source** and **destination** subscriptions must exist within the same
> **Azure Active Directory tenant**.
>
> If the tenant IDs for the source and destination subscriptions are not the
> same, you can attempt to **change the directory for the subscription**.
> However, this option is **only available to Service Administrators** who
> are signed in with a Microsoft account (not an organizational
> account).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 10):

There are two steps involved.

Like Kaushal said, the source and destination subscriptions must exist within the same Azure Active Directory tenant.

However, the subscriptions may be moved between AD tenants. There is a handy button "Change Directory" on the subscription level. [See detailed instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory). Of course, it might not be always possible, but you are saying that the old subscription is irrelevant.

Next step, move the resources between subscriptions, now in the same directory. [See detailed instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources).

Comment: These steps worked for me. Thanks @Vadim. If we have configured backup job, we need to follow the below steps to delete the restore points.                                                       https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/virtual-machines-move-limitations#virtual-machines-with-azure-backup

Comment: I moved a subscription MySub from directory DirA into directory DirB, and then moved all the resources from DirB\MySub into DirB\OtherSub. This took several hours but it happened with no downtime to my VM at all. Then finally I was able to delete the original MySub subscription without affecting or reconfiguring any of the resources. Note there are some things that can't be moved across, e.g. my role assignments were lost. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#checklist-before-moving-resources